A puzzle of parts
Find the answer below! Good luck!
|.||.|| |..|||| |.||||. ..|.|.|..|.|.|

                                    /              
                                   .      
                                  . 
                                 /
                                /
                               /
                              /

                            /
                           /
                          /
                         .
                        /
                       /
                      .

                    .
                   .
                  .
                 /
                /
               /
              /


Just to add: The non-trivial knowledge required here is not strictly needed but can be advantageous for one if one knows it.

The answer is

 7 segment

because

 treat the whitespace-separated strings of |// and . as 7-bit binary to be displayed on a  7-segment display (with | and / being 1 and . being 0), then read it:Note that "m" has 14 characters instead of 7, which indicates it is to be read as a single letter. To visualize: First bit is A, second B, and so on:The ASCII-Art 7 is simultaneously a hint and part of the answer, and the word "segment" we got out of it also has 7 letters :)


Good stuff! That’s exactly what I had in mind!
